# Python Loop over a Dictionary until i went over x elements

Tags: python

Hey i have a Short Question:

I Wanted to Iterate over my Dictionary with 7 Elements inside (Days of the Week)

and wanted to start at x element and loop until i went x elements forward
i thought about a while loop and manually set the current element to the start when reaching the end.

```
        while x in days_dict:
            final_day = days_dict[x]
            x += 1
            print(final_day)
```

What would be the best way to go about looping until you went x steps?

My Dictionary Looks like this:

```
days_dict = {"Monday":0, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":2, "Thursday":3, "Friday":4, "Saturday":5, "Sunday":6}



Desired Output for y = 1 and x = 9:
```

```
Thursday or 3
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. How do you start at `x=9` when the length of the dict is 7?

Comment: @timgeb "set the current element to the start when reaching the end" - OP wants iteration to loop around.

Comment: oh sorry i meant starting at y and going steps from y = 1 until you went 9 steps 
so i thought in the dictionary that would look like  1->2->3->4->5->6->0->1->2->3

Comment: You need to use a modulo calculation to loop around the dictionary. Also, you need to swap the keys and the values - `days_dict[x]` won't work when the key is a string but `x` is an integer

Comment: Also what does `y = 1` do? `y` only appears one time in your post.

Comment: y was supposed to be the index in the dictionary

Comment: @FelixJung in what sense? Dicts don't have an index.

Comment: dictionaries don't have indexes, they have keys and values.

Comment: ah okay then y is the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't use an integer to access a dictionary element when the index is a string. You need to swap the index and values: `day_dict = {0:'Monday', 1:'Tuesday'...}`

Rather than loop, just perform the calculation directly: `final_day = day_dict[(y+x) % len(day_dict)]`

Anyone else can correct me if I'm wrong - I'm only human

Comment: You can swap key, values in the dict like so: `days_dict = {k:v for v,k in days_dict.items()}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incredibly confusing with a bunch of unstated assumptions and very little comprehensible code, but assuming:

- you have n elements
- you want to start at element k
- you want to go l steps forward
- for both k and l, you want to cycle around if you go above n

Then you should use `itertools`, specifically `itertools.cycle` to make your iterator infinite, and `itertools.islice` to skip l and select k:

```py
x = 9
y = 1
for item in islice(cycle(days_dict), x, x+y):
    print(item)
```

also the 10th element of the week days is Wednesay, not Thursday.

And you can not generally "manually set" the current iteration state. There might be "movable" iterators in Python but I'm not aware of any (aside from file objects I guess, I've no idea what seeking in the middle of an iteration would do).

Comment: prepare for "I'm not allowed to use imports" :D

Comment: yes @timgeb i was trying to do it without libarys